# How to Return all instances of the type with the given ID in JPA SpringBoot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to return (or fetch) all the records from the database based on an ID provided by me. I'm using JPA and i'm aware of `findAll()` method but it returns all the records without any criteria, I created a custom query and it is only returning a unique value from the table but i want to return all records based on a criteria.

For example, `findAllByUserID(String UserID)` method should return all the records based on that `UserID` not just one.

I'd appreciate any help or suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the doc. There you will find the keywords you can use to declare methods in repository interfaces that will generate the according queries:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods

In your case: If userID is an attribute of your entity you can add a method

`List<YourEntity> findByfindAllByUserID(String userId)`

to your repository interface.

Comment: Amazing, it worked for me. Now i have a better understanding of jpa query methods after reading that document, thank you Simon !

Comment: Excellent answer. Great documentation link.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that you're not using any aggregate function in your select query such as `DISTINCT()`

Then make sure that the the method which is implementing that query is returning a List of you're desired result.

**here's how it should look :**

```
@Query("select t from table t where t.code = ?1")
List<Result> findAllByUserID(String UserID);
```